# JExcel getCellFormat() always null

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, jexcelapi, cell-formatting

I have a problem with Jexcel. I want read an excel file and detect for each cell the background color. I'm doing in this way :

```
Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
Colour cellColor = cell.getCellFormat().getBackgroundColour();
```

I have always NullPointerException at cell.getCellFormat(). I checked that file is correctly read and I'm also able to retrieve the content. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: And does your cell that throws NPE have some non-default format?

Answer (score 0):

Cell at (i,j) is empty, so there is no formatting information to be getted.
Before you call getCellFormat() method for a cell, you can do a test whether it's null or not. Something like below :

```
if (cell.getContents != null) {
    cellColor = cell.getCellFormat().getBackgroundColour();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No the cell was filled, thanks anyway.
I found the issue, it's seems that the excel file was formatted in a strange way and jexcel was not able to recognize the format and instead to retrieve some error or something like that it's returned null as results.